# Can I limit number of reads/writes from user IP per minute/day in firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I limit number of reads/writes from one IP in firestore?

P.S. I don't have any authentication in my app

Answer (score 1):

Limiting any sort of access by IP address is not possible with Cloud Firestore.  Instead, you should consider actually using some authentication, force requests through a backend you control, and perform per-user auditing from there.

Comment: Ok, thank you! But if I will use a Firebase Authentication, can I set some limits per user with firebase tools?

Comment: No, you will still have to manually record and check all those accesses.  There is nothing that will record or tally direct access from web and mobile SDKs.